# App rejected in iTunes Connect due to non reproducible error with in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, gdx-pay

My app has been rejected twice now due to error with in app purchase. The reviewer say that nothing happens when he request a purchase. (he does get a popup though so something happens..) The popup is something I added after the first rejection to see what was going on. Apparently the SKProductRequest yields a response without any products in it, it fails to retrieve the product.

My big problem is that I can not reproduce this in any way. When using a sandbox user I can initiate the purchase on the simulator and I can make completed purchase on test device.

I have also added the rejected build to TestFlight and downloaded it with a non test account and the in app purchase works there too every time.

I have spent days reading docs and posts here and following various check lists such as http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ but nothing works.

From the above check list I have not tried: "Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?" since I read in Apple dev docs that this is not required, it just needs to be a unique string (so I hope that is correct)

So since I can not even reproduce this using the exact build that was rejected I really have no idea how to fix this, if anyone has any input I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that I had done nothing wrong the first two times. To solve this all I did to get through the review was to add a "." to the end of the description of the in-app purchase in iTunes Connect -> Features -> In-app purchase and resubmit, then the app went through the review. Might be the weirdest review process I have ever seen and I hope I do not have to make any updates to the app in the near future ;)